# Have a footer that sit on the bottom of the page with a fixed header

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer, css-position

I would like to have my footer stay at the bottom of the page when the content is too small (I don't want to see my footer in the middle of my page).

I followed the tutorial [here](http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/making_your_footer_stay_put_with_css/) and [there](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) which both describe the same technic (min-height:100% for the container, have an explicite height for the footer, etc.).

The thing is that all those stuff doesn't work because it happens that I have a fixed header, which means that my actual content starts at body + 130px

```
body{
  padding-top: 130px;
}
```

The result is that, yes my footer sits at the bottom but, I still can scroll 130px more.

All the tutorials and questions I see are not with a fixed header.

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As default model is [content-box](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) adding a `padding-top` to an element with `height:100%;` will make its height `100% + 130px`.

So you have to add another `<div>` wrapper with auto height and add it `padding-top: 130px;`

```
<html style="height:100%;">
<body style="height:100%; margin:0; position:relative;">
    <div id="wrapper" style="min-height:100%;">
        <div id="container" style="padding-top:130px; padding-bottom:130px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" style="position:absolute; bottom:0; height:130px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works when the content is smaller that the viewport. When it's not, 130px of content go under the footer.

Comment: Right, because footer is absolute. So you have to add padding-bottom:[height of your footer]; on #container. Answer edited.

Comment: I faced an issue after: My body would have the size of the viewport and because it had a background color, when the content was bigger than the viewport, the color would be blank when scrolling. I had to add the background-color to the html element and make the body transparent.

Comment: The most sure way is to apply background-color to #wrapper and <body>. If you have to set a width it will be on #container.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `margin-top:-130px;` to your footer container.

Comment: doesn't work. I think the issue is not that much about the footer, but more about the content